# Intervention Image and imagemagick Combine images into multiple page PDF in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, intervention

I can produce a PDF with one image using Intervention Image and imagemagick but cannot find a way to combine images and output them as one multiple page PDF?

```
    $url = Image::make('https://res.cloudinary.com/image.png')->encode('png');


    $im=new \Imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob($url);
    
    $im->setImageFormat('pdf');
    $im->writeImage('my.pdf');
```

I would prefer not to save the images as files rather use the variables they are stored in

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
$images = array("https://laravel.com/images/companies/st-jude.png", "https://laravel.com/images/companies/st-jude.png");

$im = new Imagick($images);
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');
$im->writeImages('combined.pdf', true);
```